# iPhone application setting via resource file

Tags: iphone

In my iPhone application I keep application parameters in .plist file. However I have to allow user to edit these parameters.

Ex: Safari application setting can be changed in the Settings.

Can anybody assist me how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a settings bundle. The iOS Developer Documentation has [a whole section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html) about this.